# Delete a file from a directory

Tags: php, delete-file

First off, I know to use Unlink to delete a singular file from a directory. However, what I want to know is how to set that up so I can have an html interface and be able to choose through all the files in a directory.

Code would be nice, but it is unfair to ask that of you fine people. So a shove in the right direction would be just as good.

Comment: You mean you want a directory listing script, that gives links to delete the files? Start with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: did you need any class or function?

Comment: Do you want to list all the files in a directory?

Comment: Yes, list all the files in a directory, then be able to select one and delete it.

Answer (score 5):

This code lists out all the files in the given directory with delete link. When delete button is clicked, it calls a php file to delete the file using ajax(jquery) function.
Check whether more than one file don't have the same name.

list all files  in a directory

```
<?php
$directory  = "your directory path"; 
$images = scandir($directory);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
$count=1;
echo '<table border=1>';
foreach($images as $dispimage){
    if(!in_array($dispimage, $ignore)){
    echo "<tr id='del$count'><td>$count</td><td>$dispimage</td><td><input type='button' id='delete$count' value='Delete' onclick='deleteFile(\"$dispimage\",$count,\"$directory\");'></td></tr>";
    $count++;
    }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteFile(fname,rowid,directory)
{
    $.ajax({ url: "deletefile.php",
        data: {"filename":fname,"directory":directory},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
          alert(output);
          $("#del"+rowid).remove();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

deletefile.php

```
<?php
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$path = $_POST['directory'];
if(file_exists($path."/".$filename)) { 
 unlink($path."/".$filename); //delete file
}
?>
```

Comment: That is beautiful. Displays everything, however it does not delete, but I'll keep messing around with it

Comment: please check whether you have jquery.js in your path

Comment: I have made a small mistake in deletefile.php. $filename = $_POST['fname']; change it to $filename = $_POST['filename'];

Comment: Is it possible for you to delete or not? What issues do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [here](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/) for an open source version of php file manager. You can review its code or directly use it. It is not easy to do that operation by pasting sample code here.

Answer (score 0):

The following function is for deleting whole directory.

```
function readDirectory($dir){
$dir = opendir($dir);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
  {
    if($file!="." and $file!=".."){
        echo "filename: " . $file . "<br />";
    }
  }
closedir($dir);
}
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
foreach ($objects as $object) {
if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir")rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
}
}   
reset($objects);
rmdir($dir);
}
}
```

Comment: There are 2 functions one to delete whole directory and other to read whole directory and it will work only if script has permission to read, delete directory.